# set title attr in ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

The title attribute gets set prior to the ajax return. The ajax return will not change the title attribute.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '[id^=section]', function(){
        $(this).prop('title', '');
        var $this = $(this);
        answerid = $(this).attr('id');
        camNumber = answerid.slice(7);
        $.post(
          gp_ajax_settings.ajax_url,
        {
            'canvasObject': getCanvasObjectFromURL(),
            'cameraNumber': camNumber,                      
            'action': 'gp_populate_camera_title'
        },
        function(response){
            varResponse = $.parseJSON(response);
            $this.prop('title', varResponse.count + varResponse.mostRecent);
        });       
    })
```

Comment: Looks like you missing parens in your response handler. `$this` -> `$(this)`

Comment: @go-oleg Thought the same but he isn't, he sets `$this` here -> `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: @go-oleg - No, that's caching `this` so it can be called in the later callback. This is normal for this type of thing.

Comment: ah, oops didn't notice that.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the Javascript console when the handler runs?

Comment: No, the response is working properly.

Comment: what about trying $this.attr('title', varResponse.count + varResponse.mostRecent); ?

Comment: This demo shows it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/LnjxA/ (Move the mouse on the element back and forth to see the new title.) Log `$this` in the callback and replace `varResponse.count + varResponse.mostRecent` with `'test'` and see if you get the title. I don't see anything wrong, so you'll need to do some self-troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you, I have that behavior, I think I need to make the function rerun to simulate two mouse enters.

Comment: Running something like this on mouse enter to update a title attribute is a bit unorthodox. I would use a refresh button or some other means for the user to refresh this data.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I want hover query response. So, maybe an alternative to title is where I will look.